# How do I iterate over a 2D array and check each value within the array?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, conditional-statements, iteration

I am trying to iterate over a 2D array to check whether my numbers are between 1 and 9. The console's output does not reflect what I have input.

My code (input):

```
import numpy as np

array_test = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
print("this is the test: ", "\n", array_test)

for row in array_test:
    for col in row:
        if col > 0 and col <= 9:
            print(True)
        else:
            print(False)
```

Output:

```
this is the test:  
 [[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
```

I recognize the print() statement is iterating over 9 times as well which is also what I am trying to fix.
Essentially, is there a way to check for **each** number in **each** row and column, if that number is > 0 and <= 9, and if all 9 blocks in the array meet those conditions, then it prints "True" once?
Am I nesting the for-loops correctly? Is the 9 printed "True" values representing each different number?

Comment: you shouldn't be using numpy this way. Use something like `((0 < array_test) & (array_test <= 9)).all()`...

Comment: but as for the basic looping, the console's output definitely reflects the code you wrote, you are looping over each row, and over each element in that row (integers in this case). You the check if that element is `col > 0 and col <=0`, and print either true or false, so *of course* it will print once for each item in the array

Comment: Thank you @juanpa.arrivillaga , this helped resolve the issue.